# Let $a=(a+b)+(-b)$, show that $|a|-|b| \leq |a+b|$, using the Triangle Inequality

Tags: inequality

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$.  Let $a=(a+b)+(-b)$, show that $|a|-|b| \leq |a+b|$, using the Triangle Inequality.

This is currently what I have done.  I think I am going about this in a wrong way though.

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, such that $a=(a+b)+(-b)$.  Then by the Triangle Inequality, we have, $|(a+b)+(-b)+b| \leq |(a+b)+(-b)| + |b|$.  Then $|(a+b)+(-b)+b| \leq |a+b| + |-b + b| \leq |(a+b)+(-b)| + |b| \leq |a+b| + |-b| + |b|$.

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question

Comment: What have you tried? I mean, it is quite obvious to what you should apply the triangle inequality, and you're done right after that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**: $|a| = |(a + b) + (-b)| \leq |a + b| + |-b| = |a + b| + |b|$. Now subtract $|b|$ from both sides...